# How to access private member of a class from a static method of the same class in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, union-types

```
export class A {  
    private variableType: number | string;  
    public static func ( x: variableType) {
      //code 
    } 
}
```

How do I make x of the type variableType? I tried using 'this.variableType' but it's not available in a static member of the class. Also 'A.variableType' complains that A is a type but is being used as a namespace here.

Note- There were a lot of similar questions but I didn't get the solution to this. Sorry if this has already been answered.

Comment: Note that `variableType` is not a type, it's a property.  Are you looking for `A["variableType"]` maybe, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoGoMW)?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Or maybe you want a generic, that the property and static method both use?

Answer (score 0):

For your case, I'd do this way below by creating a `type`

```
type VariableType = number | string;

export class A {  
    private variableType: VariableType;  
    public static func (x: VariableType) {
      //code 
    } 
}
```

Alternatively,

```
public static func (x: A['variableType') {
  //code 
}
```

it also works but I feel like using `type` is a bit cleaner.